# Vue devServer.proxy in vue.config.js not working

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm using the following configuration in my `vue.config.js` located in the root of my repository and it's not working.

```js
  module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3030"
      }
  }
```

and this is how I'm trying to call it

```js
  return await fetch("/posts", options).then((response) =>
    response.json()
  ).catch(e => console.log("Error fetching posts", e));
```

however when I change the calling code to the code shown below everything works

```js
  return await fetch("http://localhost:3030/posts", options).then((response) =>
    response.json()
  ).catch(e => console.log("Error fetching posts", e));
```

**Edit**:

I should have mentioned that I'm using Vite for builds as that was causing some other problems for me with environment variables so it's possible they are causing problems with proxies too.

I looked into this more and it turns out that Vite does have proxy features and so I tried updating my code to use their proxy with still no luck.

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    "/posts": "http://localhost:3030/posts"
  }
})
```

Comment: `proxy` takes an object as the argument, where the property 'key' is a path. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @match I'm wanting the call to `fetch("/posts", options)` to resolve to `http://localhost:3030/posts` in dev builds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vue.config.js` is intended for Vue CLI scaffolded projects (and your config would've [worked there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-dev-server-proxy-lv5xbu?file=vue.config.js)), not for Vite projects. Vite's configuration is stored in `vite.config.js`.

Your Vite config value for [`server.proxy`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-proxy) contains an unnecessary `/posts` suffix:

```js
"/posts": "http://localhost:3030/posts"
                                ^^^^^^
```

The value should just be the base URL to which the original path is appended:

```js
"/posts": "http://localhost:3030"
```

*Example:*

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/posts': 'http://localhost:3030'
    }
  }
})
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vite-devserver-proxy-demo)